# Getting Command aborted because of exception: Command timed-out after 150 seconds error while starting roles on one of cloudera hosts

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

We are trying to add host to existing cluster and while starting roles on this host it gives "Command aborted because of exception: Command timed-out after 150 seconds" error.(Also couldnt find log of this process).

Before adding this host we had started Zookeeper in command line  not in cloudera manager interface and in cloudera Manager Zookeper seems "stopped" but i tested it in command line it is working.

After that i restarted Zookeper service on Cloudera Manager interface and get this error:

```
    NFO     org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     

minSessionTimeout set to 4000

Jul 12, 10:21:40.637 AM     INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     

maxSessionTimeout set to 60000

Jul 12, 10:21:40.642 AM     INFO    org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory    

binding to port /0.0.8.133:2181

Jul 12, 10:21:40.643 AM     ERROR   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain     

Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:91)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:53)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:121)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
```

Comment: have you stopped the zookeeper service that your started from command-line?

Comment: Did not change anything we are getting this error again and also zookeeper works just from command line when we switched on with cloudera manager it looks like running but doesnt work but starting on terminal works.